# Perspective projection with homography not working

Tags: python, opencv, projection, perspective, homography

I'm trying to replace the right side road of the following picture with light yellow polygon:

**origin**:
[image]

**desired**(created manually):
[image]

So I'm thinking using **Homography** to make it happen *(I know just adding a filled polygon will work too, but I may want to use some other source images other than a simple yellow polygon such as advertisement pics in the future).* This is a [tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/) about it and I just copy the code in it and made some change on pixles. The source image I'm using is like this:

[image]

And the first image in this post is my destination image.

Here is my code for doing the job:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# source image
source_img = cv2.imread('lightyellow.jpg')
# get four corners of the source (clock wise)
pts_source = np.array([[0,0], [20,0], [20,30],[0,30]])

# destination image
dst_img = cv2.imread('0.png')
# four corners in destination image (also clock wise):
pts_dst = np.array([[292,0], [415,0], [578,120],[415,189]])

# calculate homography
h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_source, pts_dst)

# warp source image to destination based on homography
img_out = cv2.warpPerspective(source_img, h, (dst_img.shape[1], dst_img.shape[0]))

cv2.imshow('warped', img_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However, what I got is something like this:

[image]

It's totoally wrong but I don't know why. Could somebody give me some instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it with the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# source image
source_img = cv2.imread('lightyellow.jpg')
size = source_img.shape
# get four corners of the source (clock wise)
pts_source = np.array(
                    [
                    [0,0],
                    [size[1] - 1, 0],
                    [size[1] - 1, size[0] -1],
                    [0, size[0] - 1 ]
                    ],dtype=float
                    )
#pts_source = np.array([[310,0], [440,0], [589,151],[383,151]])

# destination image
dst_img = cv2.imread('0.png')
# four corners in destination image (also clock wise):
pts_dst = np.array([[292,0], [409,0], [577,191],[421,193]])

# calculate homography
h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_source, pts_dst)

# warp source image to destination based on homography
temp = cv2.warpPerspective(source_img, h, (dst_img.shape[1], dst_img.shape[0]))

# Black out polygonal area in destination image.
cv2.fillConvexPoly(dst_img, pts_dst.astype(int), 0, 16)

# Add warped source image to destination image.
dst_img = dst_img + temp

cv2.imshow('warpped', dst_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```